# Images randomly not showing up

Tags: html, css, images, server

I just uploaded a website for a client which looked good while previewing locally. When I visit it on the server though some images aren't loading properly. It seems to be quite random, and sometimes they all load like they should. Sometimes images pop up after a sec or so.

This problem occurs in Firefox, Safari doesn't have any problems. All the image links are correct. What am I doing wrong?
This is the website: http://alturl.com/ky9o6 and this page seems to have the most problems: http://alturl.com/37czx

Comment: Can't reproduce any non-loading of images in Opera, Firefox or Safari @ OSX. Are you sure it's not your internet?? Did you ask the client if they experience any issues??

Comment: Sorry to ask, but this is a programming question how?

Comment: i just viewed both links on firefox 3.6 (on Ubuntu) and (i think) i saw all the images. Didn't see any broken images, etc. Is it possible there might be some inconsistent image extensions? For example, the images might have a mix of JPG. jpg. or jpeg while the HTML might call only the JPG version. And if the image is lower case jpg, it might not work.

Comment: @Lazarus: It is a web development question that might be programming-related (and thus relevant to SO) or might be network or other-related (and thus irrelevant). For example, if the client is running a strange HTTP server that is choking on the user agent string for Firefox, then it might be programming-related.

Comment: @Lazarus I was thinking it could be some html or css related error. Since i couldnt find a logical explanation. 

After reuploading, and viewing on several different computers i think everything loads like it should.

Comment: @ninjagecko That's a poster-child for clutching at straws and failing. An HTTP server that's choking on the user agent string for Firefox... Thom didn't indicate that they had written an HTTP Server so Firefox and the HTTP Server are likely COTS software. A quick "view source" would eliminate programming issues, if the tags are there then it's not your code unless you wrote the browser or the server.

Comment: @Thom Unfortunately I'm one of those who doesn't think that HTML or CSS is code. Webmasters would have probably yielded a much better response for you and I am thinking of your potential answers rather than just this being the wrong place for your question. Knowing where/who to ask is just as important as knowing that you need to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your web server is (very) underpowered, or the host is just having some kind of issue at the moment. While I haven't had any problem with images not displaying, the site's pages do take much longer to load than I would expect given content and my connection speed.  I don't usually get to *watch* 32k JPEG images render.
Have you contacted support at all yet?